# installing angular with npm command error in windows 7

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I am new to this technology How I can fix the ng install error and prefix error in call windows 7 professional OS

I have installed angular with npm, and get the following error:

[image]

How do I fix this error?

My files are stored here:

Comment: Where possible please copy and paste the text rather than taking a screenshot, this will allow it to be searched and help other users too. :)

Comment: k k will do it immediately

Comment: this is not fixed so far kindly let me know anybody having the answer for this

Comment: do you have node installed?

Comment: I installed but path variable not set properly

Comment: I am not able to fix this issue .in windows 7 professional os